# Kubernetes expose an app via a DNS name in minicube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a Minikube installation in which I created a simple hello-world deployment like this:

```
kubectl create deployment hello-node \
    --image=gcr.io/hello-minikube-zero-install/hello-node
```

I exposed the deployment via a service in the following way:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

Now If I call: `http://<local cluster ip>:8080` it prints "Hello World!" as expected.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to expose different deployments in the same cluster to different sub-domains of the cluster. For instance, deployment `hello1` to `hello1.my-k8-cluster.com`, `hello2` to `hello2.my-k8-cluster.com`.

I want to test this locally because later I will do the same on a real cluster.

**Question:** How to test DNS configurations of services locally? How to define sub-domains in services?

**What I tried so far:**
I went through the how-to guides [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-deployment) and [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) which though didn't bring me a clear picture on how to configure what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define subdomains on Services. Services have the form `service-name.namespace.svc.domain`.

If you want to manipulate the DNS names, you should look at [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

In order to test DNS configurations, you can use normal DNS testing tools like dig from inside a container. You can use public images like [dnsutils](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/dnsutils) or create your own testing images for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you (+1). Could you please elaborate.